# Why is the S-duct intake on the Tu-154 uniquely oblong?

Tags: aircraft-design, multi-engine, inlet, lockheed-tristar, tu-154

Is there an advantage to the oval/elliptical shape of the Tu-154's S-duct intake? It appears to be taller and an overall different shape than the side-mounted cowlings.

[image: Tu-154]

This doesn't appear to be a feature common to trijets or even on those with S-ducts.

[image: L-1011] [image: Dassault F900]

EDIT: Upon further research, it appears the 727-100 [had an oblong intake](http://warbirdsnews.com/wp-content/uploads/727finalflight-678x381.png) (Thanks Terry!), and the Hawker Siddeley Trident had an [entirely unique shape](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Hawker_Siddeley_Trident_2.jpg). So my original premise of the Tu-154 being "unique" no longer holds. I am still curious about the implications of the different designs.

Comment: So I tried looking up some 727 photos to compare, and it looks to me like this photo has an oblong intake: http://warbirdsnews.com/wp-content/uploads/727finalflight-678x381.png while this one does not: https://www.deltamuseum.org/images/site/history-aircraft/boeing-727/boeing_727_ca_late_1990s.jpg which seems odd?

Comment: The 727-100 had an oval duct and the 727-200 had a round duct.

Answer (score 13):

This doesn't fully answer the question, but the B727-100 also had an oval engine intake.

AIRLINERS magazine Sept/Oct 99 edition:

"The oval shape inlet on the 727-100 series was changed to a circular design on the stretched 727-200. This was a direct result of the new aircraft's longer fuselage. In flight, the increased lengths from the nose to the center engine inlet increased the thickness of the "boundry layer" of air on the fuselage forward of the inlet. This would have caused aerodynamic "blanking," or disruption of airflow into the center engine, without changes to the design. The circular inlet allowed a smooth flow of air into the engine, as it elevated the bottom of the inlet away from the fuselage boundry layer and into the air stream."

[image]

Comment: That's definitely a step in the right direction! On an unrelated note, I love that VP-BAP is one of the few privately owned 727s still operating in the US.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical fin is tall and thin, so it makes sense that an inlet/duct mounted in the fin and configured for optimum streamlining might not be perfectly round.